# Intellectual Property of Laptop Connectors

Tags: connector, laptop

I want to know if all the connectors of the laptop have intellectual property or copyright, I do not know how it would be said in this case, or only those modified by the companies for their specific products.

#### Apple product connectors

I assume that these connectors could not be used in any commercial product, since knowing Apple must have everything patented.

- [1]: [Apple connector 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66YqB.jpg)
- [2]: [Apple connector 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er31W.jpg)
- [3]: [Apple connector 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utKFn.jpg)

#### Connectors of multiple brands of laptops

In the case of the other brands, that there are multiple connector chargers, I do not know if they are owners and must be paid, or are free use.

- [1] - [Image connectors 1](http://www.batteryspace.com/productimages/laptop/laptop-connectors.jpg)
- [2] - [Image connectors 2](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1_d34KVXXXXcKapXXq6xXFXXXM/Free-shipping-5Lot-x-10pcs-set-Universal-tips-Notebook-DC-Power-Adapter-Socket-Plug-Connector-Laptop.jpg)

#### laptop charger usb connectors

The chargers you use are either USB Type A or USB Type C, you have no problem using such connectors.

- [1] - [laptop charger Usb Type A](http://www.batteriedeportable.com/image/matos/batterie-ordinateur-portable/70727/Chargeur-Ordinateur-Portable-LENOVO-IdeaPad-Yoga-13-ADLX65NLC2A.jpg)
- [2] - [Laptop charger USB Type C](http://www.laptopmag.com/images/uploads/4711/g/usb-c.jpg)

Investigating chargers that use usb type connectors, I found one that belongs to Lenovo, and I think you should own it.

- [Lenovo irregular USB port](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1gYsQKXXXXXbQXVXXq6xXFXXXM/20V-40W-Laptop-AC-Power-Supply-Adapter-Plug-Wall-Charger-USB-Cable-for-Lenovo-Yoga-3.jpg)

Comment: Is there a question in that sea of text?

Comment: Too many things to click on....

Comment: It doesn't matter, they'll sue you for unsafe chargers if you try and build one and sell it

Comment: @laptop2d just it is unsafe, so, if laptop charger is safe and have required certifications, don't have any problem's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. No. Yes. The second one is a thunderbolt connector which is really a mini display port connector, physically, and Apple Licenses it for free. iPod/iPhone connectors are licensed at a cost. Apple does not license out the magsafe connector and sues any similar product liberally.

DC Barrel connectors, or coaxial connectors, have been around long enough that any patent has fallen away. Multiple standards cover it.

1 is not a usb Type A. It is Lenovo's current generation power connector. Their previous one was a round barrel type. The Lenovo USB connector is a non-standard USB connector with multiple conductors that do not exist in a standard plug and used only for some of their tablet or ultra portables. The changes are proprietary. USB Type A, B, C power connectors fall under the USB Implementers Forum for licensing, though you could use the plug without license without the USB name/Symbol and USB VID/PID pin.

Comment: So, let me ask someone more, and you say is ok or not. **Thunderbolt** and **MagSafe** have a licenses for free, but iPod/iPhone i need to pay, if wanna use for some products. The **coaxial connectors** many company's try to create pay licenses but they can't, so this connectors are licenses for free. And if wanna use any USB Connectors for any product, i don't use **the USB name/symbol USB VID/PID pin**.

Comment: Magsafe no. Apple is very very protective of it. Thunderbolt yes. iPhone if you pay yes. The coaxial connectors are not under patent as far as i know, what companies are you talking about. The USB connector is afaik, because the license is for the USB trademarks of the VID/PID and logo. Of course IANAL and some of the companies involved have very powerful lawyers.

Comment: Just ask you, i don't get it, if coaxial connectors are licenses for free or not, Apple connectors, clear all, and the USB connector, i need to pay someone for use the logo in my product. What is **IANAL**?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales I Am Not A Lawyer.